# hashing password with salt

Tags: php, hash

I have searched through Internet and found the function for hashing the password. But
i'm having trouble to deal with hashed password  stored in the the database. the function i'm using generate the random password as it is concatenated with the random generated salt.
the problem comes when a user wants to change his password.

```
current_password = random hashed password( which must match the one stored in db).

if(current_password == $db_password){

    enter new password

}
```

the above condition wont be true since the password is always random.

**my function**

```
function cryptPass($input,$rounds = 9) {
    $salt = "";
    $saltChars = array_merge(range('A','Z'),range('a','z'),range(0,9));
    for($i = 0;$i < 22; $i++){
        $salt .= $saltChars[array_rand($saltChars)];
    }
    return crypt($input,sprintf('$2y$%02d$', $rounds).$salt);
}
$pass = "password";
$hashedPass = cryptPass($pass);

echo $hashedPass;

i have 3 column in my user table (id, username, password).
```

can any one tell me how to properly use this function,
or is there a best way to do this?

Comment: Store the salt in the table along with the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the same steps, as you would for the login. Check if the entered old password matches the password-hash in the database, then create a hash from the entered new password and store it.

PHP already has a function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a hash, and a function [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check whether the entered password matches the stored password-hash.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

So your code would look something like this:

```
if (password_verify(current_password, $db_password))
{
  enter new password
}
```

Comment: is password_hash() available in php versions prior to php 5.5?

Comment: @dxcoder1 - Yes there is a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions. So you can use the same "future proof" functions (later you can just remove the compatibility pack). Even for PHP before 5.3.7 there is a possiblity, have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22260436/575765).

Answer (score 1):

You want to store the `$salt` generated in the database **along with the hashed password**.  Then when you come to check the password you will be able to get the salt from the database and use it in the hashing process again.

So your database table with have an extra column in it called "salt"

```
(id, username, password, salt)
```

Comment: This can not be the problem, because the crypt() function includes the salt in the resulting hash-value, and for verification it extracts the salt automatically from the stored hash-value.