# salted to unsalted password md5 php

Tags: php, passwords, md5, salt

I'm moving to a other shopping cart and want to import the customers. However the new shopping cart uses a other password system. I would like to convert the old passwords + salt to a single md5.

This is the code for the old shopping cart:

```
if (md5(md5($password) . md5($salt)) == $hash) {}
```

This is the code for the new shopping cart:

```
password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "'
```

Is it possible to convert it into a single md5 string?

Comment: And the new code looks like.....?

Comment: password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You would need the original value (the password) to recreate the hash using a different algorithm. Since you don't have the password and a hash is purposefully not reversible, you cannot get the "single MD5" value.

You'll have to adapt the code in your new system to work with the old hash values.
And you should use something better than MD5 while you're at it, it's entirely inadequate for secure password hashing. [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) is the PHP state-of-the-art.

Comment: I quote someone else on SO: *"The best methods are PBKDF's such as PBKDF2, bcrypt and scrypt. crypt should not be used if possible, `password_hash()` is an implementation of crypt and bcrypt and not a separate algorithm. Users passwords can always be compromised if they choose a bad password. One way cryptographic hashes or PBKDF's cannot be reversed, but they can be brute forced (e.g. using a dictionary attack)."* -- Your views on this?

Comment: Password-related topics seem to be somewhat *primarily opinion-based* (at times), as I've noticed on SO since I first signed up and reading the many posts as I go. Some hashing algorithms are not supported by older versions of PHP, yet some do have a patch to make them run, but not all of them which concerns me (for some of the servers I maintain); it's a constant battle.

Comment: @Fred-ii- There isn't really much opinion involved, but probably not everybody was up to speed until somewhat recently and PHP's inconsistent support for good algorithms has contributed to that situation. The advent of `password_hash` has largely resolved that debate IMO. Fact are: random salts are necessary, MD5/SHA1 are unsuitable, PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt are the accepted state of the art algorithms, `password_hash` is a good implementation you should be using unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: You took the words right out of my mouth about *"PHP's inconsistent support for good algorithms"* and then some. As for the `password_hash()` function; some of the servers I maintain have yet to upgrade their version of PHP and I have no control over that since they are hosted servers, therefore I have to do with what I have to work with; for now. Cheers, always a pleasure.

Comment: You are aware that there's an implementation of `password_hash` in PHP you can use from PHP 5.3 and up?

Comment: Yes, [`this one`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) I do believe.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - With the compatibility pack you can use the `password_hash()` even before PHP 5.3.7, you only need to change the algorithm as i described in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22260436/575765). This is not the optimal solution but is the best you can do. BTW it is not bad to use the `crypt()` function, just difficult to do it right, password_hash() itself calls crypt().